# Error using method edges.each |edge|

Tags: ruby

I typed this from a tutorial in Sketchup Ruby API.

```
centerpoint = Geom::Point3d.new(0,0,0)
vector = Geom::Vector3d.new 0,0,1
model = Sketchup.active_model
entities = model.active_entities
eges = entities.add_circle( centerpoint, vector, 10)
vertices = []
edges.each do |edge|
vertices << edge.start
  vertices << edge.end
end
vertices.uniq!
vertices.each do |vert|
   entities.add_cpoint(vert.position)
end
```

I get this error message.

```
Error: #<SyntaxError: <main>: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input
edges.each do |edge|
                    ^>
```

I would like to know why.

Comment: I think if you indent everything between a do/end block you'd see that you're missing an `end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unexpected end-of-input` generally means, you are missing an `end` somewhere. 
You need to write one more `end` in your code. Look at the block that you start at the end.

```
vertices.each do |vert|
   entities.add_cpoint(vert.position)
end
```

Put an `end` underneath here.